# How to query with get_posts() for posts with any tag

Tags: tags, get-posts

I need to do a simple post query that will get any post that has at least one tag. This is my current code that gets the posts with tag ID 27 or 36, but I need to modify it to get all posts with at least one tag.

```
$args = array(
    'numberposts' => 5,
    'tag__in' => array(27,36)
);
$myposts = get_posts( $args );
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could try this.

```
$all_tags = get_tags();
$tag_id = array();
foreach( $all_tags as $tag ) {
    $tag_id[] = $tag->term_id;
}

$args = array(
    'numberposts' => 5,
    'tag__in' => $tag_id
);
$myposts = get_posts( $args );
```